# How to prove that $\Sigma_{n=1}^{N-1}{\sin^2\frac{p\pi{}n}{N}} = \frac{N}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

Here $p$ is a known integer constant ($p > 0$).
I know that this is true for a fact (checked numerically in Matlab and it holds), but I'm just not able to prove it. I noticed a similar problem related to the sum of reciprocal of sine-squared ([Sum of the reciprocal of sine squared](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122836/sum-of-the-reciprocal-of-sine-squared)), but I'm getting nowhere with this problem.

Comment: My bad - the RHS of the equation should be $\frac{N}{2}$, not $\frac{N+1}{2}$ - changed it in the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can prove that the sum is equal to $N/2$.  Here, just recognize that

$$\sin^2{y} = -\frac14 (e^{i y}-e^{-i y})^2 = \frac12 - \frac14 (e^{i 2 y} + e^{-i 2 y}) = \frac12 - \frac12 \Re{[e^{i 2 y}]}$$

so the sum is

$$\begin{align}&= \frac12(N-1) - \frac12 \Re{\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} e^{i 2 p \pi n/N}}\\ &=  \frac12(N-1) - \frac12 \Re{\frac{e^{i 2 \pi p/N}-e^{i 2 \pi p}}{1-e^{i 2 \pi p/N}}}\end{align}$$

That last expression is $-1$ because $p \in \mathbb{Z}$.  The result follows.

Comment: this might be a dumb question - Isn't $\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}{r^n} = \frac{1-r^N}{1-r}$? So the exponential sum would be $\frac{1 - e^{i2p\pi}}{1-e^{i2p\pi/N}}$. How are you getting $e^{i2p\pi/N}$ in the numerator instead of 1?

Comment: @R.K.: Your expression is valid when the sum starts at $n=0$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Use $\displaystyle\cos2A=1-2\sin^2A\iff\sin^2A=\frac{1-\cos2A}2$

Then utilize

[How can we sum up $\sin$ and $\cos$ series when the angles are in arithmetic progression?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro?rq=1)

or

[Sines and cosines of angles in arithmetic progression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297452/sines-and-cosines-of-angles-in-arithmetic-progression)

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact $\sin(x) = \frac{1}{2i} [e^{xi}-e^{-xi}]$ (by Euler's formula), expand, and use
 geometric series.